# Adding classpath location in sbt

Tags: java, scala, matlab, sbt

I am in the process of writing a scala application which using Matlab in the backend. Matlab provides a Java API to call processes. The matlab help page [here](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/setup-environment.html) gives an example where the class path is specified in the command line argument like so: `javac -classpath matlabroot/extern/engines/java/jar/engine.jar MyJavaCode.java`.

In my project I use sbt; how would I specify the classpath in the sbt configuration?

Edit: Sbt version: 1.2.8

Comment: Please [edit] your question to specify sbt's version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this using the following lines in my build.sbt:

````scala
unmanagedJars in Compile ++= Seq(new java.io.File("/usr/local/MATLAB/R2019b/extern/engines/java/jar/engine.jar")).classpath
unmanagedJars in Runtime ++= Seq(new java.io.File("/usr/local/MATLAB/R2019b/extern/engines/java/jar/engine.jar")).classpath```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can add this line in your build.sbt to specify your main class:

```
mainClass in Compile := Some("com.example.MyScalaCodeMain")
```